# unable to compile my c++ project after install VS 2012

Tags: visual-c++

> Error 1 error MSB4018: The "MIDL" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.FileTracker' threw an exception. --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file
>   specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002) at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32
>   errorCode) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Shared.NativeMethodsShared.ThrowExceptionForErrorCode(Int32
>   errorCode) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Shared.NativeMethodsShared.GetShortFilePath(String
>   path) at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.FileTracker..cctor() --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace --- at
>   Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.ComputeOutOfDateSources()
>   at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.SkipTaskExecution() at
>   Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() at
>   Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.Execute() at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext()
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 1179

Comment: Wow. I can't read that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this problem affecting all projects?

I had similar problem when porting code from older version of VS. Form my experience the most errors are generated because paths. I do not remember details but using output paths explicitly (done in older versions) creates problem since project conversion mechanism tries to use macros and as a result in empty, wrongly formatted paths.

My advice is to verify all settings pertaining to output. Make sure OutputPath, TargetDir and others are set properly. Try changing settings and use to inherit from parent. 
Create empty project of the same type and compare properties of both.